# How to classify images based on solid color areas and repeating patterns

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a simple image classification problem. I am writing a jigsaw puzzle application which needs to categorize images to difficulty levels (e.g, easy, medium, hard).

I want to develop an simple algorithm for this classification, the difficulty based on factors like large solid colored areas and repeating patterns on the image. Such classification can be seen in following website.
http://www.whitemountainpuzzles.com/Shop-by-Difficulty/departments/136/
http://www.seriouspuzzles.com/sjigsbeg.asp

I want to automate this classification without much human interventions. Is this possible and whats the best way to approach it. (not worried about performance, simple is good, does not need huge accuracy)

More details and examples about difficulty http://www.ulillillia.us/tipsntricks/jigsawpuzzledifficultytrick.shtml

**EDIT :** I want to come up with a simple algorithm to classify images roughly or give a score

Comment: Voting to close as **Too broad**. Wikipedia and Google are your guys for this one, not Stack Overflow

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Seems vague.

Comment: the problem with the solid color areas shouldn't be too hard to solve using for e.g. floodfill (since performance doesnt matter). as for the pattern-recognition, thats a bit more difficult, but should be possible to solve using OpenCV

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I have updated the question now. I want to come up with an algo to roughly classify images. Can I use histograms? or something like that so that score can  be given. Then based on the score rage difficulty can be determined.

Comment: @pats why don't you try it ? Histograms should be easy to implement, it would probably only take you a few lines of Matlab. If it gives good results, implement it in Java, otherwise try another approach. You're not asking about a programmatic issue, you are asking SO to do the whole research work for you

Comment: I am asking ideas to solve my programming problem. I tried histograms, but that does not help me to classify images, based on classification criteria i laid out above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version of "simple algorithm". It's based on pairwise comparison between pieces but after bluring with diameter about 1/10 of piece size. So yes, you have to set number of pieces in horizontal and vertical directions first. Default number used in all tests is 40*25 = 1000 pieces. Work complexity (or difficulty if you let me use such word in this context) here is average similarity between pieces. I know it's weird measure but the more similar pieces you have the harder the puzzle is. Right?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class JigsawComplexityTest {
    private static final int defaultHorizontalCount = 40;
    private static final int defaultVerticalCount = 25;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String test1 = "http://www.ulillillia.us/images/mgscreen.png";
        String test2 = "http://www.ulillillia.us/images/easyjigsawpuzzleimage.png";
        String test3 = "http://www.ulillillia.us/images/hardjigsawpuzzleimage.jpg";
        String test4 = "http://students.cec.wustl.edu/~billchang/cse559/project2/result9.jpg";
        String mostlyGreen = "http://keera.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Screenshot_2014-07-27-22-26-23.png";
        String grass = "http://p1.pichost.me/i/75/2000933.jpg";
        String flowerFields = "http://p1.pichost.me/i/14/1371715.jpg";
        String people = "http://captital-connection.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/capitalconnectionpeople.jpg";
        String nature = "http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wallpapers_1920x1200/nature/1/4/pond-between-the-flowers-nature-hd-wallpaper-1920x1200-32983.jpg";
        String puzzle1 = "http://jigsawpuzzlesforadults.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5000-Piece-Jigsaw-Puzzle-Needle-Mountains.png";
        String puzzle2 = "http://jigsawpuzzlesforadults.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/18000-Piece-Jigsaw-Puzzle-Paraadise-Sunset.png";
        String puzzle3 = "http://jigsawpuzzlesforadults.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5000-Piece-jigsaw-puzzle-PuzzleRavensburger-Views-of-Modern-Rome-.png";
        String puzzle4 = "http://jigsawpuzzlesforadults.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5000-Piece-Puzzle-James-Rizzi_-City-.png";
        System.out.println("Test1: " + getComplexity(test1));
        System.out.println("Test2: " + getComplexity(test2));
        System.out.println("Test3: " + getComplexity(test3));
        System.out.println("Test4: " + getComplexity(test4));
        System.out.println("Mostrly green: " + getComplexity(mostlyGreen));
        System.out.println("Grass: " + getComplexity(grass));
        System.out.println("Flower fields: " + getComplexity(flowerFields));
        System.out.println("Nature: " + getComplexity(nature));
        System.out.println("People: " + getComplexity(people));
        System.out.println("Puzzle1: " + getComplexity(puzzle1));
        System.out.println("Puzzle2: " + getComplexity(puzzle2));
        System.out.println("Puzzle3: " + getComplexity(puzzle3));
        System.out.println("Puzzle4: " + getComplexity(puzzle4));
    }

    public static double getComplexity(String url) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
            return getComplexity(img, defaultHorizontalCount, defaultVerticalCount);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    public static double getComplexity(BufferedImage img, int xCount, int yCount) {
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();
        Color[][] pixels = new Color[h][w];
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
                pixels[y][x] = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
        int pw = w / xCount;
        int ph = h / yCount;
        pixels = blur(pixels, pw / 5, ph / 5);
        double sumCompl = 0;
        int denominator = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < xCount; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < yCount; j++)
                for (int n = i; n < xCount; n++)
                    for (int m = j; m < yCount; m++) {
                        if (i == n && j == m)
                            continue;
                        sumCompl += compareSubimages(pixels, i * pw, j * ph, n * pw, m * ph, pw, ph);
                        denominator++;
                    }
        return sumCompl / denominator;
    }

    private static Color[][] blur(Color[][] input, int dx, int dy) {
        if (dx < 2)
            dx = 2;
        if (dy < 2)
            dy = 2;
        Color[][] ret = new Color[input.length][input[0].length];
        for (int y = 0; y < input.length; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < input[y].length; x++) {
                int r = 0;
                int g = 0;
                int b = 0;
                int denominator = 0;
                for (int i = -dx; i <= dx; i++) {
                    if (x + i < 0 || x + i >= input[y].length)
                        continue;
                    for (int j = -dy; j <= dy; j++) {
                        if (y + j < 0 || y + j >= input.length)
                            continue;
                        Color c = input[y + j][x + i];
                        r += c.getRed();
                        g += c.getGreen();
                        b += c.getBlue();
                        denominator++;
                    }
                }
                ret[y][x] = new Color(r / denominator, g / denominator, b / denominator);
            }
        return ret;
    }

    private static double compareSubimages(Color[][] pixels, int x1, int y1, 
            int x2, int y2, int pw, int ph) {
        double ret = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pw; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < ph; j++) {
                Color c1 = pixels[y1 + j][x1 + i];
                Color c2 = pixels[y2 + j][x2 + i];
                ret += Math.max(Math.max(Math.abs(c1.getRed() - c2.getRed()) / 255.0, 
                        Math.abs(c1.getGreen() - c2.getGreen()) / 255.0),
                        Math.abs(c1.getBlue() - c2.getBlue()) / 255.0);
            }
        return 1.0 - ret / (pw * ph);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Test1: 0.6769529450450067
Test2: 0.28125444354771767
Test3: 0.9002461442832157
Test4: 0.9406619849710389
Mostrly green: 0.8951158950955296
Grass: 0.8590196334404887
Flower fields: 0.7202705256209023
Nature: 0.6829507611296955
People: 0.5517856536390812
Puzzle1: 0.49445824310139086
Puzzle2: 0.6918959038799397
Puzzle3: 0.7519219343473392
Puzzle4: 0.7367090900702122
```

PS: Complexity in this context is difficulty of work, not complexity of data on picture.

PPS: The algorithm is extremely not optimized. It's just proof of concept.

Comment: Very close to what I was after. Really Nice work. Thanks. Only issue I noticed was patterns, (e.g http://rlv.zcache.com.au/black_white_stripe_vertical_straight_lines_pattern_poster-r562429fe820f429f857cd8b463d6a7e9_zth1q_8byvr_1024.jpg) gave 0.5 values. According to the range 1 - highet difficulty and 0 is lowest isnt it?

Comment: @pats, hmm, interesting. 0.5 is pretty low comparing to other cases. May be it's possible to add (combined with my proposal) another type of analysis focused on frequencies of pairs of neighboring pixels with different colors oriented in horizontal and vertical directions...